# React firebase multifle users loging and signup

Tags: react-hooks, firebase-authentication

I need to know how to implement multiple user login with user role using react and firebase

I try to search how to do that but still cannot find it, And I need to create user role in firebase store and add tokens for that how to do it,

Answer (score -1):

Implementing multiple user logins with different roles in React using Firebase involves several steps, including user authentication and managing user roles within Firebase.

**User Authentication with Firebase**:
**1 Set Up Firebase Authentication**:
Initialize Firebase in your React app and set up authentication methods (email/password, Google sign-in, etc.).

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  // Your Firebase config here
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

**2 Implement User Sign-up and Login:**
Create components or pages for user registration and login using Firebase authentication methods. This can include creating users with different roles during sign-up.

**Managing User Roles:**
**1 Role-Based Access Control (RBAC):**
Define user roles within your application. This can be as simple as storing a role property in the user's profile in Firebase.

```
// Set user role during registration
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Add role to the user profile
    userCredential.user.updateProfile({
      displayName: 'user',
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle errors
  });
```

**2 Token-Based Access Control:**
Utilize Firebase Custom Claims or tokens to manage user roles and permissions. Custom Claims allow you to assign roles to users and control access to resources based on those roles.

```
// Set custom claim for user role
firebase.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, { role: 'admin' })
  .then(() => {
    // Custom claim set successfully
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle errors
  });
```

**Implementing Role-Based Authorization:**
**1 Check User Roles:**
Once users are authenticated, fetch their role information from Firebase and implement logic to restrict access to certain parts of your application based on their roles.

```
// Check user role
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
if (user) {
  user.getIdTokenResult().then((idTokenResult) => {
    const role = idTokenResult.claims.role;
    // Implement logic based on user role
  });
}
```

**2 Secure Firebase Firestore/Realtime Database:**
Use Firebase Security Rules to control access to data in Firestore or Realtime Database based on user roles.

**Notes:**
Ensure proper error handling and validation during user sign-up and role assignment.
Use Firebase's authentication and security features carefully to maintain data security and integrity.
Adapt the code examples according to your application's architecture and specific requirements.
Remember, managing user roles and permissions is critical for the security of your application. Always follow best practices and validate user actions on both the client and server sides.